# Redirection in Ubuntu

Tags: terminal, find, ubuntu-14.04, io-redirection

Good evening. Set up Ubuntu 14.04,I started to use Terminal and encountered on a strange thing:
I tried to find a file and hand the control to "more".

```
find -name qwerty1 | more
```

But something very strange goes on:given below both strings of code lead to the same result.

```
find -name qwerty1 | more 
find -name qwerty1
```

The output is:

```
find: `/run/cups/certs': Permission denied
find: `/home/architec/.gvfs': Permission denied
find: `/home/architec/.config/enchant': Permission denied
find: `/home/architec/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
/home/architec/qwerty1
find: `/var/lib/lightdm': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/udisks2': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/sudo': Permission denied
find: `/var/lib/polkit-1': Permission denied
```

The question is why are both results are simular?

Answer (score 0):

By piping with more you are saying to paginate the output of find command. Although you are not changing any condition like file name to search in with find command.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use both the command with superuser mode.

i.e.

sudo find -name qwerty1 | more

or

sudo find -name qwerty1

and then give superuser/root password.

May this will help you.